# Trying double precision math in openCL doesn't compile

Tags: c++, c, math, opencl, gpu

I am trying to do some double precision math operations in an openCL kernel.  I have cl_khr_fp64 enabled and I can do simple +-*/ operations in double, but when I try to use the built in math functions (for example, exp ) the code fails to compile.  If I switch to float it works.

I read on the Khronos site that math functions are overloaded to support double if you enable cl_khr_fp64, which I did. (http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/mathFunctions.html)

I am working on a new MacPro with the D700 GPU and I read that only some of the math functions are overloaded to include double (http://developer.amd.com/knowledge-base/) but exponential is on the list of included functions.  Also, when I send this code to the CPU instead of the GPU it fails as well.

Here's the code of my kernel.  It's just an extension of the Hello World! example on the Apple developers site.  If I switch u to be a float it works or if I replace exp(u) with u (as in the first part of the conditional) it also works.  This is just a toy problem I'm trying to get to work before I start implementing my real code, but I have to get this working before I move one.  I've also tried double_exp, expd, and native_exp.  They all lead to the code compiling but then I get runtime errors.

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
kernel void square5(global double* input, global double* output, double mul)
{
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    double u = 5.0;
    if(i==0) {
        output[i] = mul*u*input[i]*input[i];
    } else if (i==1023) {
        output[i] = mul*u*input[i]*input[i];
    } else {
        output[i] = 0.25*mul*exp(u)*(input[i-1] + input[i+1])*(input[i-1] + input[i+1]);
    } 
}
```

Here's the error log

```
/Users/me/Downloads/OpenCL_Hello_World_Example/mykernel.cl:12:30: error: call to '__fast_relax_exp' is ambiguous
    output[i] = 0.25*mul*exp(u)*(input[i-1] + input[i+1])*(input[i-1] + input[i+1]);
                         ^~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:4496:22: note: expanded from macro 'exp'
#define exp(__x) __fast_relax_exp(__x)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:4494:30: note: candidate function
__CLFN_FD_1FD_FAST_RELAX(__fast_relax_exp, native_exp, __cl_exp);
                         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:416:27: note: expanded from macro '__CLFN_FD_1FD_FAST_RELAX'
inline float __OVERLOAD__ _name(float x) { return _default_name(x); } \
                      ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:4494:30: note: candidate function
__CLFN_FD_1FD_FAST_RELAX(__fast_relax_exp, native_exp, __cl_exp);
                         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:417:28: note: expanded from macro '__CLFN_FD_1FD_FAST_RELAX'
inline float2 __OVERLOAD__ _name(float2 x) { return _default_name(x); } \
                       ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:4494:30: note: candidate function
__CLFN_FD_1FD_FAST_RELAX(__fast_relax_exp, native_exp, __cl_exp);
                         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:418:28: note: expanded from macro '__CLFN_FD_1FD_FAST_RELAX'
inline float3 __OVERLOAD__ _name(float3 x) { return _default_name(x); } \
                       ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:4494:30: note: candidate function
__CLFN_FD_1FD_FAST_RELAX(__fast_relax_exp, native_exp, __cl_exp);
                         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:419:28: note: expanded from macro '__CLFN_FD_1FD_FAST_RELAX'
    inline float4 __OVERLOAD__ _name(float4 x) { return _default_name(x); } \
                       ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:4494:30: note: candidate function
__CLFN_FD_1FD_FAST_RELAX(__fast_relax_exp, native_exp, __cl_exp);
                         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:420:28: note: expanded from macro '__CLFN_FD_1FD_FAST_RELAX'
inline float8 __OVERLOAD__ _name(float8 x) { return _default_name(x); } \
                       ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:4494:30: note: candidate function
__CLFN_FD_1FD_FAST_RELAX(__fast_relax_exp, native_exp, __cl_exp);
                         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:421:29: note: expanded from macro '__CLFN_FD_1FD_FAST_RELAX'
inline float16 __OVERLOAD__ _name(float16 x){ return _default_name(x); }
                        ^
1 error generated.
Command /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Libraries/openclc failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I said that the code compiles for double_exp, expd and native_exp but leads to runtime problems.  It actually doesn't compile for native_exp either. double_exp and expd still lead to runtime problems.  Sorry for mistake.

Comment: Does your Device support double precision?

Comment: It clearly says it can't find the function for double (all the candidates are floatn types), does the device support double? Maybe it can be due to fast relaxed math enabled? Due to that macro expansion?

Comment: It does support some double functions, like +-*/. I've tried every setting for IEEE relaxation in the build settings but none work. It doesn't thrown an error when I just multiply by u, as in the first part of the conditional. Im starting to think the AMD documentation is wrong about supporting double functions. Or I'm misreading the documentation.

Comment: My MacPro late 2013 with D300 supports "cl_khr_fp64" but the CPU device only supports "cl_APPLE_fp64_basic_ops". Are you positive you've selected the GPU device and not the CPU? Use clGetDeviceInfo for extensions supported.

Comment: @Dithermaster - Yeah, I went through a good deal of work trying to figure out how to select the 'offline' vs 'online' GPU, since only one is hooked up to the displays. I investigated CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS on both GPUs, and my CPU and cl_khr_fp64 is only found on my CPU but cl_APPLE_fp64_basic_ops is on all 3 compute devices. I guess the "basic_ops" means it doesn't fully support double? I can't find much documentation on it. What is strange is that I can't use exp(double) on my CPU either, even though it lists cl_khr_fp64 as a supported extension.